# why we can't use text file instead of html file for web pages?

Tags: html, browser

as you know txt files and HTML files are text-based documents and I want to know why we use .HTML extension?
I mean both of them (text and HTML files) are text-based but when I open txt file, my browser can't render it.
help me, please.

Comment: because the browser sees the content type of the file and loads it as plain text. So why are you writing HTML has a text file?

Answer (score 1):

The `.txt` extension indicates a **plain** text file. HTML is text based, but it isn't **plain** text, it is formatted with HTML.

Software uses file extensions (or Content-Type headers if we're using HTTP) to determine how to treat a file.

Comment: yes but i want to know why HTML file was created? i mean we can use .txt file and declare to browser in first line with (!doctype HTML) for define this file is html

Comment: @Aradolfati — Because putting a Doctype in doesn't make it an HTML document. If it has a .txt extension then it is a *plain text file*. It might just happen to start with `<!DOCTYPE html> is a string that appears at the start of HTML documents to trigger standards mode`. It would not be desirable for that to be treated as HTML.